# How to check each line within a pipe delimited file to be same of different

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a pipe-delimited file which can have millions of records. What I want to do is sort the file and remove if there are any duplicate lines there.

Then I need to check the first 32 columns and see if the content from first line matches with second line. If yes, then delete the second line and again check the first line with third line(which now will become second line due to removal of previous line since it was same). if this is also same then remove the third line as well and continue to compare first line with subsequent lines from file until we get a mismatch.
For example: Input File:

```
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|...|a32|acb@sma.com
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|...|a32|acd@sm.com$1553:2015-02-14 
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|...|a32|axwer@xi.com30:2015-03-01 
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|...|a32|acbw@ma.com$121:2015-01-31 
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|...|a32|art@ma.com$293:2015-02-28 
b|b1|b2|b3|b4|...|b32|asmi@g.in$542:2013:05:24 
b|b1|b2|b3|b4|...|b32|kasmi@g.in$542:2013:05:24 
b|b1|b2|b3|b4|...|b32|asmi@g.in14:2013:05:24
b|b1|b2|b3|b4|...|b32|asmi@g.in$542:2013:05:24 
b|b1|b2|b3|b4|...|b32|asmi@g.in232:2014:05:24 
c|c1|c2|c3|c4|...|c32|Asce@ita.in 
c|c1|c2|c3|c4|...|c32|$200:2011:12:06 
c|c1|c2|c3|c4|...|c32|kst@gre.in$214:2001:01:31
```

There are 33 fields in above example and "..." is used to represent the continuity. So here as you see, first 4 lines are same (comparing only till field number 32 which is shown in example having a value of "a32"). So I need to keep just the 1st one and delete others. Similarly for columns starting with `b`, we have 5 records which are the same, so again delete the last 4 and keep the first one.
For records starting with `c`, we just have 3 records so we need to delete last 2 and keep 1st one. 
Hence the output file would be some thing like this:

Required Output file:

```
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|...|a32|acb@sma.com
b|b1|b2|b3|b4|...|b32|asmi@g.in$542:2013:05:24 
c|c1|c2|c3|c4|...|c32|Asce@ita.in
```

I was thinking of using a regular loop and sed command to get this done but it slows the process significantly. 
So, is there a way where we can use `ack` and make this search/manipulation faster?

Comment: @Mohsen Thans for formatting.

Comment: There is community and everone help to community, So no needed to thanks.

Comment: Are there always exactly 33 fields, or can there be more? I'm asking because it's easier to split and compare lines if we only have to consider two fields per line: everything before the rightmost pipe and everything after it.

Answer (score 3):

Sort on keys 1 to 32 (-k1,32), with *vertical bar* as delimiter `-t'|'`.
`-u` means: output only the first line of an equal run (of combined keys).
See `man sort` for details of `sort`'s options.

```
sort -t'|' -k1,32 -u infile
```

The above code, of course, results in a sorted output.
However, if you want to maintain the same sequence of first-found lines as per the input file, then use:

```
nl -s'|' -ba infile | sort -t'|' -k2,5 -u | sort -t'|' -k1 -n | cut -d'|' -f2-
```

`nl` prefixes sequential line numbers. These line numbers are `cut` after the `sort` steps.
Note that the output of this second method is the same as [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202174/2343)'s Perl solution.

Comment: `nl -s'|' -ba infile | sort -t'|' -k2,33 -u | sort -n | cut -d'|' -f2-` cool +1

Answer (score 1):

Peter's `sort` approach is almost certainly going to be the most efficient, I suggest you use it. For the sake of diversity, here's a Perl solution:

```
perl -F"\|" -lane  'push @G,$_ unless ++$k{join("\|",@F[0..31])}>1;
                    END{print join "\n",@G}' file
```